# pattern.firstMatch is get Error : Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, pattern-matching

I'm the first iPhone developer. What I want to do is distinguish special characters in text fields. So I tried to use a regular expression. But it shows me the error.

```swift
    @IBOutlet weak var walletNameField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func nextButtonFuc(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let pattern = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9가-힣ㄱ-하-ㅣ\\s]$", options: .caseInsensitive)
        if walletNameField.text!.isEmpty {
            callAlert("test")
        } else if walletPasswordField.text!.isEmpty {
            callAlert("test")
        } else if confirmField.text!.isEmpty {
            callAlert("test")
        } else if walletPasswordField.text != confirmField.text {
            callAlert("test")
        } else if walletNameField.text!.count > 10 {
            callAlert("test")
        } else if walletPasswordField.text!.count  < 8 ||
            walletPasswordField.text!.count >= 20 {
            callAlert("test")
        } else if pattern.firstMatch(in: "\(walletNameField.text!)", options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, walletNameField.text!.count)) { //get Error Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context
            callAlert("test")
        }
    }
```

Error is

> Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

What did I do wrong? I find it difficult to solve this problem.

And I try to hide my keyboard when I touch anywhere. However, the function itself is an error. Why is there an error?

```swift
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

// Error is  Declaration 'touchesBegan(touches:withEvent:)' has different argument labels from any potential overrides
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `firstMatch` does not return a `Bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare `firstMatch` with a value as `if` expects  A BOOL

```
} else if pattern.firstMatch(in: "\(walletNameField.text!)", options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion,range: NSRange(location:0,length:walletNameField.text!.count)) != nil  {  

}
```

Or use `if let`

```
} else if let first =  pattern.firstMatch(in: "\(walletNameField.text!)", options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion,range: NSRange(location:0,length:walletNameField.text!.count))  {  
   print(first)
}
```

---

Regrading `touchesBegan` you need to use latest syntax [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. @Sh_Khan  Could you let me know if there's a simpler way to solve this without using regular expressions? For example, special characters + numbers + no letters or special characters

Comment: Entering a special character in the text field does not display an alert. I think the regular expression is wrong. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your second problem i.e. hiding the keyboard the function should be :-

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
   }
```